# Where does Adobe Reader store the "Page Display" setting?

Tags: windows-registry, adobe-reader

I like the "Page Display" option in Adobe Reader to be set to "Single Page Continuous", so it doesn't suddenly jumps to the next page.

But for some unknown reason the Adobe Reader at my work (version 9.1.1) doesn't always remember this setting. Does anybody know where Adobe Reader stores this setting? I suspect its somewhere in the registry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you know PDF files can specify initial layout and zoom settings that take effect when you open them? (For example, when you choose the Export to PDF command in OpenOffice, a dialog box lets you specify the [initial view and other user interface options](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Writer_Guide/Exporting_to_PDF#Initial_View_page_of_PDF_Options_dialog) that are saved in the PDF file.)

Your problem may be caused by certain PDF files changing the view settings when you open them. In that case, Adobe Reader has accessibility options to ignore the settings specified in PDF files.

I don't have Adobe Reader 9.1.1. But in Adobe Reader 8.2.0, I was able to go to Edit, Preferences, Accessibility, and there's a check box "Always use Page Layout Style" with a drop down box where you can choose "Single Page Continuous".

Comment: Thanks for this.  In Adobe Reader X, I was having this problem.  `Preferences -> Accessibility -> Always use Page Layout Style` fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a script for changing the settings (or do it manually in the registry).

Below example sets the display options to "smooth" for Acrobat X:

```
REM Set Acrobat X settings to Smooth text for LCD/Laptop
REM Set to LCD
reg add "HKCU\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\10.0\Originals" /V bAntialiasText /T REG_DWORD /F /D 1
REM Set to "For Laptop/LCD screens"
reg add "HKCU\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\10.0\Originals" /V benableDDR /T REG_DWORD /F /D 1
REM Set threshold 
reg add "HKCU\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\10.0\Originals" /V iAntialiasThreshold /T REG_DWORD /F /D 18
```

Answer (score 1):

In Preferences- Accessibility, change the Override Page Display setting for the required style of display. All PDF files will then open as specified

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what Bavi_H already said, Reader (which I don't have for some reason on this machine, so I can't check this) also has the possibility of specifying command line switches (for example, so it sets the page to fit width every time), so there is a possibility that it has that one as well.

Check it, what can you lose.

Answer (score 0):

Bavi_H is right - each doc has its own settings embedded into it. There is a little trick you can do to help though. In Reader 10, go to `Edit -> Preferences -> Documents` and check "Remember previous display settings for each document".

That way when you open something for the first time you can change the settings and they'll be remembered for that document. Changing it to override the document specific settings would likely involve some registry work as mentioned about. Not sure if you're up for that, but best of luck to you.