# What is this PDF feature named?

Tags: pdf

Scrolling between pages works in one of two modes.  Either it is continuous, such that as you scroll (slide the hand up) past the current page, the following page scrolls up with it, allowing you to see a good portion of both pages simultaneously.  The other mode is where you reach the end of the current page, the following page is not visible until you change pages, at which time you're at the top of the next page, but cannot see the previous page anymore.  What is that called?  It's a per-document attribute/property.  I do not think this is a feature settable in any reader (acrobat reader, foxit reader).

I already know how to view pages side by side or other arrangements.  I'm looking to learn the name of the above feature so that I can configure it on a per-document basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my version of Acrobat Reader (version 9.4), this is settable.  Go to View -> Page Display.  Then select between Single Page and Single Page Continuous.  A check mark will appear next to the mode you have selected.

Based on the above, this feature must be called Single Page.

Comment: Ah so it is a reader setting after all.  Not sure why I was so convinced it was a document feature.  Perhaps I had some documents which had usage attributes preventing changing of the continuous display mode properly.

Comment: If it was a document feature, I'd expect it to be documented in §8.1 “Viewer preferences” of the [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf), which it isn't. Many viewers have such a setting, but it's global, not per-document.

Comment: Actually, PDFs [can change the Reader settings](http://superuser.com/questions/115341/where-does-adobe-reader-store-the-page-display-setting/) when you open them, so in some cases it **is** a document setting. I examined some test PDFs made with OpenOffice.org and found the relevant command in the PDF file is `PageLayout`. In the PDF Reference Gilles linked to, page 140 in Section 3.6.1 "Document Catalog" describes the PageLayout key is "A name object specifying the page layout to be used when the document is opened". @Gilles